# Typescript index signature and type augmentation with constant value

Tags: typescript, constants

I have a question regarding index signature and type augmentation using a constant value.

Here is a snippet of the code i want to use. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

```
class Component {
    greet() {
        console.log( 'hello' );
    }
}

const PROPERTY = 'foobar';
interface Element {
    // I want here to augment Element
    [param: typeof PROPERTY_COMPONENT_INSTANCE]: Component | undefined
}

// ... somewhere else ...

const el = document.getElementById( '#myasd' );

// To be able to get a "Component|undefined" here
const comp = el[PROPERTY];
if( comp ) {
    comp.greet();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure, you are going to get an object of type Component,
you can define your type as follows

`const comp = el[PROPERTY] as Component | undefined`